# How to test for null of Double variable

Tags: c#, json

I am accessing an endpoint and getting JSON back. I loop through the object and I put the value in a double field. Sometimes the filed will be null. How do I handle the null case. Currently my code looks like:

```
double scanning_risk = double.Parse(JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.ToString());
```

Just FYI. I was able to handle null errors with INT variables using the GetValueOrDefault() function like:

```
int Firm_Id = JSONrecord[i].Firm_Id.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Here is how I am handling strings:

```
string Deleted_At = JSONrecord[i].Deleted_At == null 
                  ? "" 
                  : JSONrecord[i].Deleted_At.ToString();**
```

Is there a similar  GetValueOrDefault() function for double or a similar way to handle the case when a double filed is null?

Thank you!

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault` is a method of `Nullable<T>`, which works fine for doubles.  What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

It should work the same as for `int`s:

```
double scanning_risk = JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.DefaultOrEmpty();
```

Assuming, of course, that `scanning_risk` is a `Nullable<double>` field.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how do you know?  The OP is calling `ToString()` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return to you value or default value (0) for `double`:

```
double scanning_risk = 0;
double.TryParse(JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.ToString(), out scaning_risk);
```

If you can have `null` in `JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk` use:

```
double scanning_risk = 0;
double.TryPerse(JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk == null ? "" : JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.ToString(), out scanning_risk);
```

Also this method returns right default(0) value for `double` if string contains non numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks eveyone.

This is what I ended up using:

```
 double spread_charge = row.spread_charge == null 
                      ? 0 
                      : double.Parse(row.spread_charge.ToString());
```

where my json class has double? spread_charge

Comment: When you run it in debugger what is the type of `row.spread_charge`?

Answer (score -1):

```
double scanning_risk = 0;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.ToString())) {
     scanning_risk = double.Parse(JSONrecord[i].scanning_risk.ToString());
}
```

Comment: How can you tell `0` and `null` apart?

Comment: If the value is `null`, this will just throw a NRE.